# Use downloaded global OSM data in Android offline app

Tags: openstreetmap, tiles, android, mobile, offline

I am about to develop my first Android app (so I am a newbie in mobile app development). For this I will need OSM data of the whole globe, but only data with tags highway, boundary, waterway and natural (here only water bodies). This data I will download (still need to figure out how I can download such a big data set, Overpass API??) and later style it in my own way in QGIS. The map I would like to use as a base map in my offline app.

Now I know that I can use map tiles to render the data faster in a map viewer. However, I still have some problems understanding why and how it is possible to use so much data in an app when the data storage restrictions of apps are a few MB's. The map tiles would still use the whole OSM data I downloaded, which is several GB's, isn't it?

Comment: I think your question is a bit too general yet and a lot of reading is needed from your side to assess and define the develpment strategies you can follow. Working offline with the whole globe is challenge and I hardly imagine why you need all at once. A question you need to solve is what you need offline. The tiles for visualization or some vector information to do something else? Have a look to http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Downloading_data#Huge_amounts_of_data and http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Frameworks

Comment: Map tiles are small images (raster) of a particular view (fixed style and scale) of the information in osm. The osm data is a vector data base. There is quite a difference between them

Comment: Hi @Marco , Basically I need the tiles as visualization. The map should only display street network and water bodies, but for the whole globe. It is a base map for the app to diplay POI's and add those by the user on the map.

Comment: Regarding the raster / vector data: I am aware of tiles being raster data. But I never crated those and I am wondering that it would use pretty much space on the device to have such raster files stored in the app.